# clustering algorithm for Multi-dimensional data

Tags: algorithm, dataset, cluster-analysis, data-mining, data-analysis

I am a data-mining newbie and need some help with a high dimensional data-set (subset is shown below). It actually has 20 dimensions and several thousand rows.
Q: How we can clustering similar(teams) and if any similarity metrics can be calculated from this data and is my data need any normalization process due each value its differ from other. I have looked Cosine similarity , and Euclidean , jaccard  approaches, however unsure how to approach this problem.

numbers in this array that mean each team include some faculties only 4 , 12 or none 0 has been completed particular job ,

```
number of faculties for each team are differ from others 
team1= 50 faculties
team2= 53  
team3= 46 .. etc. 

                                " type of job"
 "ROW"   "CPU"   "PRT"   "CR"    "CV"      "TR"    "PO"    "ME"    "HC"      
 team1     4      12      15      9          2      2       0        17 
 team2    13       0      0       22         7      5       1        1 
 team3    10       1      12      3          1      0       3        0
  .....
 teamN ...etc..
```

Comment: Please don't repost the essentially-same question. Instead, consider improving your previous question to make it more focused: [Is data correct to apply clustering algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277111/is-data-correct-to-apply-clustering-algorithm)

Comment: my questions are : is any need to normalize these values , what are the best similarity measure to deal with this kind then best algorithm to cluster high dimension data .

Comment: depend on this data i have looked for best similarities measure Euclidean and cosine after applying normalization to avoid random distribution and to make data within similar scale . the problem is what are the best clustering algorithm can deal with this type of data ?

Comment: what do you think best algorithms can deal with this type of numeric data to test it , it is so difficult to test at all , at lest 3 or 5 that may help me , thanks

Comment: OK , i will try it , but do you think these values required normalization process before applied similarity measures and clustering algorithm or not , these values are coming randomly ,that is my final issue ?

Comment: Yes, you need normalization.

Comment: for the following question issue .. normalization suppose MAX-MIN how about the following question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159834/what-is-the-best-normalization-metric-for-the-following-data]  how about distributions of Denominator values .. thanks

Comment: For you data a nonlinear normalization is probably best.